# How to generate iTunes App icon URL by app id

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I know I can search for iTunes App Store information using http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=509943167.
But, **is it possible** to generate link to iTunes App Icon using only app id?
For example: just like Facebook graph API do for fanpage avatar: https://graph.facebook.com/eminem/picture?type=normal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the URL you provided, it returns a JSON blob where one of the properties is `artworkUrl512`. In this case, the corresponding value is

http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/063/Purple/v4/1a/99/31/1a9931f2-0070-68c8-a870-80c04a62b7bd/MaDEtHfroqMKzpU0q0VUCg-temp-upload.vikzbwtt.png

[image]

Comment: I know, i'm aware of that. But I need direct url, without fetching app information first and then look for app url

Comment: I doubt that's possible to do.

Comment: if it is really not possible, then your answer would be only solution.